# Angular Directive creating duplicate elements

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, angular8, angular-directive

I have an Angular directive that is working for the most part, but it is creating duplicate injections of button and ul class="dropdown" after my element. Can anyone see why this would duplicate? Works fine in plain js.

My Directive:

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '.dropdown-container'
})
export class DropdownDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.customization-option');
    // /////// Adding li's for each option ////////
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
      var option = dropdown[i].querySelectorAll('option');
      var options = [];
      var drop;
      for (var x = 0; x < option.length; x++) {
        options.push(option[x].innerHTML);
      }

      drop = "<button>" + options[0] + "</button><ul class='dropdown'>";
      options.forEach(addOptions);
      drop += "</ul>";
      console.log(drop);
      dropdown[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', drop)
    }

    function addOptions(value) {
      drop += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
    }


  }

  @HostListener('click') onClick(e) {

    var thisDrop = this.el.nativeElement;
    var opt = thisDrop.querySelector('.dropdown').children;
    var buttonDrop = thisDrop.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('button');
    thisDrop.classList.toggle("active");


    for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
      opt[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var optValue = this.innerHTML;
        buttonDrop.innerHTML = optValue;
        this.parentElement.classList.remove('active');
      });
    }

  }

}
```

In my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="storeRequest">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>What can we do for you?</h4>

    <div class="col-2-container">
      <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="dropdown-container" appDrop>
          <label for="topic">Choose a Topic*</label>
          <select name="topic" id="topic" class="customization-option" (change)="toggleForm($event)">
            <option value="Become a Sponsor" selected>Become a Sponsor</option>
            <option value="Host a Fundraising Event">Host a Fundraising Event</option>
            <option value="Give a Donation">Give a Donation</option>
            <option value="General Information">General Information</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-2-container">
      <div class="fieldset">
        <label for="stCompany" appFocus>Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="stCompany" autocomplete="on" appFocus />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2-container">
      <div class="fieldset">
        <label for="stFirstname" appFocus>First Name*</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname2" id="stFirstname" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stFirstname" />
        <span *ngIf="!storeRequest.get('stFirstname').valid && storeRequest.get('stFirstname').touched" class="validation-error">Please enter your first name.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <label for="stLastname" appFocus>Last Name*</label>
        <input type="text" name="stLastname" id="stLastname" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stLastname" />
        <span *ngIf="!storeRequest.get('stLastname').valid && storeRequest.get('stLastname').touched" class="validation-error">Please enter your last name.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2-container">
      <div class="fieldset">
        <label for="stAddress1" appFocus>Address Line 1*</label>
        <input type="text" name="stAddress1" id="stAddress1" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stAddress1" />
        <span *ngIf="!storeRequest.get('stAddress1').valid && storeRequest.get('stAddress1').touched" class="validation-error">Please enter your address.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <label for="stAddress2" appFocus>Address Line 2</label>
        <input type="text" name="stAddress2" id="stAddress2" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stAddress2" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2-container">
      <div class="fieldset city">
        <label for="stCity" appFocus>City*</label>
        <input type="text" name="stCity" id="stCity" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stCity" />

      </div>



        <div class="fieldset zip">

          <label for="stZip" appFocus>Zip Code*</label>
          <input type="text" name="stZip" id="stZip" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stZip" />
          <span *ngIf="!storeRequest.get('stZip').valid && storeRequest.get('stZip').touched" class="validation-error">Please enter your zip code.</span>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!--Col-2 end-->

    <div class="col-2-container">
      <div class="fieldset">
        <label for="stEmail" appFocus>Email*</label>
        <input type="email" name="stEmail" id="stEmail" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stEmail" />
        <span *ngIf="!storeRequest.get('stEmail').valid && storeRequest.get('stEmail').touched" class="validation-error">Please enter your valid email.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <label for="stPhone" appFocus>Phone Number*</label>
        <input type="tel" name="stPhone" id="stPhone" autocomplete="on" appFocus formControlName="stPhone" />
        <span *ngIf="!storeRequest.get('stPhone').valid && storeRequest.get('stPhone').touched" class="validation-error">Please enter your valid phone.</span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <h4>Best time to contact you?*</h4>

    <div class="col-2-container">
      <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="dropdown-container" appDrop>
          <label for="bestTime">Select a Time*</label>
          <select name="bestTime" id="bestTime" class="customization-option">
            <option value="Morning" selected>Morning</option>
            <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
            <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h4 *ngIf="!general">Does the organization have a 501 (c)3 Status?</h4>
    <div *ngIf="!general" class="col-2-container">
      <div class="radios-container">
        <div class="radio-round">
          <input type="radio" checked class="radio" name="c3" id="yes501" />
          <label for="yes501">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-round">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" name="c3" id="no501" />
          <label for="no501">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <h4>What makes your organization a great fit for Zaxby's?</h4>

    <div class="">
      <textarea rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="required">*Required</div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button class="button gray">Cancel</button>
      <button class="button red">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

It works for the most part, but I get 2 buttons and 2 ul's created after each dropdown. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see your code, you are using the `.customization-option` class in two of your `<select>` options. So when you are looping through the `querySelectorAll('.customization-option')`, it iterates twice with the `dropdown.length` creating a duplicate of your values.

In this case, if you need to specifically access only your second `<select>` option's class, then just pass the index and access the element.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.customization-option')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Angela. You pointed me in the right direction. I switched

```
document.querySelectorAll('.customization-option');
```

to

```
var dropdown = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.customization-option');
```

after defining el as ElementRef

```
constructor(public el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.el = el;
  }
```